# While trying to publish to Index Layer, getting the error as <none> is not a term while creating data frame

Tags: here-olp

While trying to publish to Index Layer using spark-connector for olp, getting the error as  is not a term while creating data frame.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to Encoders used in Spark which doesn't work correctly with case classes.

Used the below library and steps to fix the issue

https://scalapb.github.io/sparksql.html